# Laravel store with number loop

Tags: php, laravel

How can I have same data stored as much as provided number?

#### Example

Store `abc`, `10` times

both `abc` and `10` are coming from form request

## Code

```
nonuiqueAmount: 10
nonuiqueSerial: "abc"


 if(!empty($request->input('nonuiqueSerial'))) {
   foreach($request->input('nonuiqueAmount') as $item) { // this returns error
       $barcode = new Barcode;
       $barcode->serial_number = $request->input('nonuiqueSerial');
       $barcode->save();
   }
 }
```

**Error**:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: It seems to be saying `$request->input('nonuiqueAmount')` is not an array (or similar), but you only seem to expect 1 value anyway.

Comment: I would rather store `abc` and `10` instead of `abc,abc,abc,abc.....`

Comment: So what you have is the equivalent of `foreach(10 as $item)` … does that really make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a for loop:

```php
// nonuiqueAmount: 10
// nonuiqueSerial: "abc"


if (!empty($request->input('nonuiqueSerial'))) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $request->input('nonuiqueAmount', 0); ++$i) { // I've added the zero as a default value to prevent unnecessary loops
        $barcode                = new Barcode;
        $barcode->serial_number = $request->input('nonuiqueSerial');
        $barcode->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop works only on arrays, and is used to loop through each key/value pair in an array. [w3schools docs](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_foreach.asp)

Your `nonuiqueAmount` is an `int`. I would suggest simply stick with basic for loop

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $request->input('nonuiqueAmount'); $x++) { 
   $barcode = new Barcode;
   $barcode->serial_number = $request->input('nonuiqueSerial');
   $barcode->save();
}
```